# get a list of comma separated values in python and use that list to perform a command as many times as necessary with each value

Tags: python, api

I'm sure this is something easy to do for someone with programming skills (unlike me). I am playing around with the Google Sites API. Basically, I want to be able to batch-create a bunch of pages, instead of having to do them one by one using the slow web form, which is a pain.

I have installed all the necessary files, read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python), and successfully ran [this](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/samples/sites/sites_example.py) sample file. As a matter of fact, this sample file already has the python code for creating a page in Google Sites:

```
elif choice == 4:
      print "\nFetching content feed of '%s'...\n" % self.client.site

      feed = self.client.GetContentFeed()
      try:
        selection = self.GetChoiceSelection(
            feed, 'Select a parent to upload to (or hit ENTER for none): ')
      except ValueError:
        selection = None

      page_title = raw_input('Enter a page title: ')

      parent = None
      if selection is not None:
        parent = feed.entry[selection - 1]

      new_entry = self.client.CreatePage(
          'webpage', page_title, '<b>Your html content</b>',
          parent=parent)
      if new_entry.GetAlternateLink():
        print 'Created. View it at: %s' % new_entry.GetAlternateLink().href
```

I understand the creation of a page revolves around page_title and new_entry and CreatePage. However, instead of creating one page at a time, I want to create many.

I've done some research, and I gather I need something like

```
page_titles = input("Enter a list of page titles separated by commas: ").split(",")
```

to gather a list of page titles (like page1, page2, page3, etc. -- I plan to use a text editor or spreadsheet to generate a long list of comma separated names).

Now I am trying to figure out how to get that string and "feed" it to new_entry so that it creates a separate page for each value in the string. I can't figure out how to do that. Can anyone help, please?

In case it helps, this is what the Google API needs to create a page:

```
entry = client.CreatePage('webpage', 'New WebPage Title', html='<b>HTML content</b>')
print 'Created. View it at: %s' % entry.GetAlternateLink().href
```

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, you probably didn't want to change the `raw_input` into an `input` to get `page_titles`. That means the user now has to put quotes around their answer or it won't work (or, worse, if they type something like `sys.exit()`, it will work by running the code they typed!). (You may have been looking at code meant for Python 3 instead of 2, where `raw_input` was renamed to `input`, and the weird old `input` function was thrown away. But judging by your `print` statements, you're still using Python 2.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to "use that list to perform a command as many times as necessary with each value", that's a `for` loop. (It may be an implicit for loop, e.g., in a `map` call or a list comprehension, but it's still a loop.)

So, after this:

```
page_titles = raw_input("Enter a list of page titles separated by commas: ").split(",")
```

You do this:

```
for page_title in page_titles:
    # All the stuff that has to be done for each single title goes here.
    # I'm not entirely clear on what you're doing, but I think that's this part:
    parent = None
    if selection is not None:
        parent = feed.entry[selection - 1]

    new_entry = self.client.CreatePage(
        'webpage', page_title, '<b>Your html content</b>',
        parent=parent)
    if new_entry.GetAlternateLink():
        print 'Created. View it at: %s' % new_entry.GetAlternateLink().href
```

And that's usually all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to loop over a dict object and create multiple pages. Here is a little snippet to get you started.

```
import gdata.sites.client

client = gdata.sites.client.SitesClient(
        source=SOURCE_APP_NAME, site=site_name, domain=site_domain)

pages = {"page_1":'<b>Your html content</b>',
         "page_2":'<b>Your other html content</b>'}

for title, content in pages.items():
    feed = client.GetContentFeed()

    parent = None
    if selection is not None:
        parent = feed.entry[selection - 1]

    client.CreatePage('webpage', page_title, content, parent=parent)
```

as for feeding your script from an external source I would recommend something like a csv file

```
##if you have a csv file called pages.csv with the following lines
##page_1,<b>Your html content</b>
##page_2,<b>Your other html content</b>

import csv

with open("pages.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        title, content = row
        client.CreatePage('webpage', title, content, parent=parent)
```

Comment: I think you want `for title, content in pages.items()` here.

Comment: But I think the idea is that he's getting a list of titles (see the `page_titles = input(…)` line), so what he actually needs is to iterate over _that_, and look up `pages[title]` for each one.

Comment: It's saying: TypeError: '_csv.writer' object is not iterable

Comment: that's because I'm a jerk =), you should be using a reader and if I wasn't a jerk that's how I would have written it.